# An error occured, please run package manager

Tags: apt, package-management, kde

In Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS I got a message in the little icon tray iin the bottom left corner of the screen, the icon being a red circle with a white line. When I click on it, it says

> "An error occured, please run Package Manager from the right click
>   menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message
>   was: 'Error: BrokenCount>0' This usually means that your installed
>   packages have unmet dependencies."

Could the problem be the fact that I interrupted the installation of KDE Plasma because it was taking a long time? If so, what can I do to fix the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `apt-get install --fix-broken` will probably fix the issue.

Comment: I ran it with sudo and it removed kompozer. While the problem was not the KDE installation, it did the job; I no longer have the icon appearing. Thanks, and also here's an easter-egg: 'apt-get moo' :P Thanks again